# How to pass a 2D array to function with a row offset like M*i in C?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

```
for(int i=0; i < n; ++i){

    //Find the  leading element in a+M*i
    if(!find_leading_element((a+M*i),n-i,m,&rowLead,&columnLead)){
        return;
    }
    //Get the dividable from a[rowLEad][columnLead]
    divide = (double)1/a[rowLead][columnLead];
    printf("The divide from current matrix is %d\n\n",divide);
    //Swap the current row = i with rowLead in matrix a+M*i
    swap_rows((a+M*i),n-i,m,i,rowLead);
}
```

I am working on a small school project for reducing matrices but having some troubles passing the 2D array with an offset.

I need the `find_leading_element` to get a 2D array and return via the pointers the row and column of the leading element in that matrix.

Therefore `find_leading_element` returns the row and col relative to the matrix it got, and it is okay I will handle it later on. Now the issue is with passing the 2D array with a row offset.

So with each iteration I will pass the matrix but with one row less. Since I can't change the declaration for `find_leading_element`, I need to pass the function with `double a[][M]`, does it mean it is passed by value?

```
bool find_leading_element(double a[][M], int n, int m, int * row, int * column) {

    printf("In Find Leader got the matrix\n");
    print_matrix((double (*)[M])a,n,m);
    for(int i=0; i < m; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j < n; ++j){
            if(*(&a[0][0]+j*M+i) != 0){
                *row = j;
                *column = i;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

double a[N][M];
printf("Enter matrix:\n");
if (!read_matrix((double (*)[M]) a, n, m)) {
    printf("Invalid matrix!\n");
    return ERROR;
}
```

What is the best way to do it? The way I do it here it only receives on the second iteration one row.

Comment: `find_leading_element((a+M*i), ...` and `find_leading_element(double a[][M], ...` are not consistent. How is `a` declared in caller?

Comment: Added the declaration for a and initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware pointer arithmetics is not raw addresses arithmetics.

As `a` is a 2D array declared as `double a[N][M];` it will decay to a pointer to a row. That means that the address of the i-th row is `a+i` and not `a+M*i`.

The latter is used when you simulate a 2D array with a 1D one: `int aa[N*M];`. Here `aa` will decay to an `int` pointer and the beginning of the i-th row would be at `aa+M*i`.

The call should be:

```
//Find the  leading element in a+M*i
if(!find_leading_element((a+i),n-i,m,&rowLead,&columnLead)){
    return;
}
```

Comment: @RomanTimm: My bad. It is just a typo. It should be `a+i`. Post edited.

Comment: It helped but I got in trouble later on. What is the difference (in this question) would be between `*(a+i+rowLead)[columnLead]` and `a[i+rowLead][columnLead]`? Since the former didn't work in my code but the later fixed it. I think that the former indexed wrong elements in the array.